# add random passwortgenerator in the same function

Tags: powershell

Is it possible to add a random password generator in this function?

```
Function Create-User([String] $Username, [String] $Name, [String] $Surname, [String] $OU, [String] $Group){

    $User = Get-ADUser -Filter {sAMAccountName -eq $Username}
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I added the `$password` variable inside of your function that you can use however you choose. The value stored in the variable is a secure string. If you need to provide the password value to the user, you can capture the value first by not piping into the `ConvertTo-SecureString` cmdlet.

```
Function Create-User([String] $Username, [String] $Name, [String] $Surname, [String] $OU, [String] $Group){

$password = ((33..126) | ForEach-Object {[char]$_} | get-random -count 20) -join "" | ConvertTo-SecureString -asplaintext -force
New-AdUser -accountpassword $password # You will need to add the rest of your parameters here

}
```

You can change the `-count` value to whatever meets your security policy requirements. The example above generates a 20 character password using random characters from the ASCII table positions 33 through 126. You are free to update that range however you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a small function to generate a password.
Below code creates a password with a mixture of uppercase- and lowercase letters, digits and if you want that also symbols.

```
function New-Password {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
        [ValidatePattern("[0-9]")]
        [int]$Length = 12,

        [switch]$IncludeSymbols
    )

    $pw = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
    if ($IncludeSymbols) {
        $pw += "!$%^-_:;{}<>#&@]~"
    }
    return -join ([Char[]]$pw | Get-Random -Count $length)
}
```

Use in your Create-User function like this:

```
Function Create-User {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [String]$Username, 
        [String]$Name, 
        [String]$Surname,
        [String]$OU
    )

    # call the New-Password function to get a plain text password.
    $plainTextPassword = New-Password -Length 8
    $securePassword    = $plainTextPassword | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force

    # the New-AdUser cmdlet has many parameters. Best use splatting for these.
    $splat = @{
        SamAccountName  = $Username
        Name            = $Name
        Surname         = $Surname
        Path            = $OU
        AccountPassword = $securePassword
        # add more parameters as you see fit here
        # see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/new-aduser?view=win10-ps
    }
    New-AdUser @splat

    # output the user and the generated password because you will not be able to retrieve this later..
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        User     = $Username
        Password = $plainTextPassword
    }
}
```

Example:

```
Create-User -Username jdoe -Name 'John Doe' -Surname Doe -OU 'OU=Users, OU=DepartmentX, DC=yourdomain, DC=com'
```

will output

> ```
> User Password
> ---- --------
> jdoe 4Wvhud02
> ```